# Ruby: Convert string with special characters in hex format into regular string

Tags: ruby, string, hex, character, pack

I am working on a customer order automation script in Ruby 2.2.
This takes an incoming customer e-mail body and splits it into various parameters.

However, I encounter an issue where any "special characters" (e.g. Æ, Ø, Å, ü, ...) are converted into hex format, i.e. "Ø" becomes "C398".

I would like to convert these into their correct characters.
So far, I've managed to get the following working:

```
puts ["C398"].pack('H*') => Ø
```

However, the problem comes when I have a long e-mail body where only select few characters are in their hex format. I.e. if I run above on the full address I get:

```
puts s = ["P.P. C398rums Gade"].pack('H*') => ��9����
```

Is there a smart way to single out the "hex" characters and convert only those, while retaining the other parts of the long mail body string intact?

Thank you!

Martin

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" in "I would like to convert these into their correct characters."? A simple example (that includes your desired output)  be helpful.

Comment: How come you got an email body with clear text and hex encoding mixed together? And how can you know which one is Hex and which one is Text...? (i.e. how do you know if `44` represent a number or a letter) ... seems to me the issue might be something different... my experience shows that you should have an escape character that indicates Hex encoding, allowing you to isolate and replace these occurrences.

Comment: I am with Myst, also you mentioned that the "special characters" are being converted ... Exactly what is doing the converting?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs above. The e-mail I load into Ruby looks normal when I look at it in my one.com server inbox or via Outlook, i.e. foreign/special characters like Æ, Ø, Å, ü, ... are shown correctly. However, when I load the mail into Ruby, most text looks correct - yet the foreign/special characters are replaced by their Hex counterparts (e.g. C398 for Ø) - with no clear way to identify them. Hence I was hoping that maybe some gem or code could "scan" for "Hex matches" and replace them by the relevant character (i.e. Æ, Ø, Å, ü, ...). Hope that makes sense?

Comment: It may be an issue with how I load the mails originally (i.e. using the ruby gem Mail). I'm not sure if I need to enforce a given encoding to make it work properly, but so far I've not had luck with going that path either - but if some of you have experience with such a solution, let me know!